# Is it possible to remove duplicates for an specific row in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

My query:

```
select substr(name,1,1), name 
from authors
group by name 
order by name;
```

This is the data (MySQL)

```
1 C Chris
2 C Cary
3 D Doug
4 D Dave
5 D Drake
6 E Eli
7 E Elma
8 E Ezra
```

And this is what I want to achieve.

```
1 C Chris
2   Cary
3 D Doug
4   Dave
5   Drake
6 E Eli
7   Elma
8   Ezra
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us sample table data and also your current query attempt.

Comment: And tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: Which RDBMS? Oracle has the LAG function but others database don't have direct way to do it

Comment: It is not clear. Show your source data and desired output. Also , the queries  you have tried if any

Comment: I have edited my question. Is it clear now?

Comment: Typically done in the above presentation layer.

Comment: I think it's normal for SQL to repeat the group value for each row, I'll do it in the presentation then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go...

```
select @substr := if(substr(@name,1,1) <> substr(name,1,1),substr(name,1,1) ,'') as groupedSubstr
,@name := name as name
from (  
select name from authors
group by name
order by name  
) a;
```

Comment: hey @beautiful.drifter thank you so much for the help. it worked like a charm! I highly appreciate your help!

Comment: @RapirapLeeYo glad I could help!  Would appreciate it if you accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Done. Thanks again!